# Checking equality in RSpec

Tags: ruby, caching, rspec

I'm testing the storing object to cache.

I'm checking the equality

```
cached_object.should == original_object
```

The object has a lot of nested objects so here's only a snippet of whole message:

```
...
 @e164s=
   -             [#<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c88b0
   +             [#<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c420
                   @index="1",
                   @value="16508045106">,
   -              #<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c8838
   +              #<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c358
                   @index="2",
                   @value="17065664321">,
   -              #<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c8720
   +              #<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c2b8
                   @index="3",
                   @value="12025553356">,
   -              #<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c86a8
   +              #<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c240
                   @index="4",
                   @value="18185554321">,
   -              #<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c8630
   +              #<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c1c8
                   @index="5",
                   @value="14085664321">,
   -              #<Mappers::E164:0x000000051c8518
   +              #<Mappers::E164:0x0000000525c128
                   @index="6",
                   @value="16505554321">]
...
```

As you can see, the values of objects are equal but objects inside the original_object and cached_object have different object_id's

How to rewrite test to make it pass?

Comment: Perhaps the real issue is that the objects in question do not properly redefine `==`.

Comment: Good article related to this question: http://techbot.me/2011/05/ruby-basics-equality-operators-ruby/